# Getting ImportError: No module named azure.storage.blob when doing python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-blob-storage

When I try to do `python manage.py syncdb` in my Django app, I get the error **ImportError: No module named azure.storage.blob**. But thing is, the following packages are installed if one does `pip freeze`:

`azure-common==1.0.0
azure-mgmt==0.20.1
azure-mgmt-common==0.20.0
azure-mgmt-compute==0.20.0
azure-mgmt-network==0.20.1
azure-mgmt-nspkg==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource==0.20.1
azure-mgmt-storage==0.20.0
azure-nspkg==1.0.0
azure-servicebus==0.20.1
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.1
azure-storage==0.20.3`

Clearly **azure-storage** is installed, as is evident. Why is **azure.storage.blob** not available for import? I even went into my `.virtualenvs` directory, and got in all the way to `azure.storage.blob` (i.e. `~/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob$`). It exists!

What do I do? This answer here has not helped: [Install Azure Python api on linux: importError: No module named storage.blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787450/install-azure-python-api-on-linux-importerror-no-module-named-storage-blob)

*Note: please ask for more information in case you need it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. To alleviate that, I followed this discussion here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/51#issuecomment-148151993

Basically, try `pip install azure==0.11.1` before trying `syncdb`, and I'm confident it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread similar with yours, please check my answer for the thread [Unable to use azure SDK in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213764/unable-to-use-azure-sdk-in-python).

Based on my experience, Python imports the third-party library packages from some library paths that you can check them thru codes `import sys` & `sys.path` in the python interpreter. So you can try to dynamically add the new path contains the installed `azure` packages into the `sys.path` in the Python runtime to solve the issue. For adding the new library path, you just code `sys.path.append('<the new paths you want to add>')` at the front of the code like `import azure`.

If the way has not helped, I suggest you can try to reinstall Python environment. On Ubuntu, you can use the command `sudo apt-get remove python python-pip` & `sudo apt-get install python python-pip` to reinstall `Python 2.7` & `pip 2.7`.(Note: The current major Linux distributions use Python 2.7 as the system default version.)

If Python 3.4 as your runtime for Django, the apt package names for Ubuntu are `python3` and `python3-pip`, and you can use `sudo pip3 install azure` for `Python 3.4` on Ubuntu.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm on Python2.7. Both methods did not work. I added `import sys` and `sys.path.append('<path here>')` to my python code, restarted gunicorn and re-ran syncdb. I got exactly the same error as before. Next, I ran `sudo apt-get remove python python-pip` `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install python python-pip`. After this, I ran `syncdb` again - and I still get the same error. The tragedy is that in 2 other environments (both local), the code `from azure.storage.blob import BlobService` never gave me trouble. But now, I keep running into `No module named azure.storage.blob`.